# Description/text_body while creating event through exchangelib

Tags: python, exchangelib

While creating an event, is there any way to add description or do anything with item.text_body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `text_body` is marked as a read-only field in exchangelib, so changes to that field will have no effect when saving the calendar item: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/d9e7e12b6bf4aab72f36587a90eb06ea5eaea322/exchangelib/items.py#L148

In EWS, `text_body` is a best-effort attempt at converting an HTML-formatted body to simple text. This is done server-side.

You can, however, create text-only body content just fine using exchangelib by setting the `body` field instead.